# Explain conditional probability?

Tags: probability

Consider 3 baskets. Basket A contains 3 white and 5 red marbles. Basket B contains 8 white and 3 red marbles. Basket C contains 4 white and 4 red marbles. An experiment consists of selecting one marble from each basket at random. What is the probability that the marble selected from basket A was white, given that exactly 2 white marbles were selected in this process.

I know P(AB) = 33/176 and I understand how to get there.
However I'm not sure why P(B) = 73/176.

Here is the answer, but can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

By Bayes rule, the required probability is equal to
$$P(A_w|W=2)=\frac{P(W=2|A_w)P(A_w)}{P(W=2)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{8}}{\frac{73}{176}}=\frac{33}{73}$$ since $$P(W=2|A_w)=P(B_w)P(C_r)+P(B_r)(C_w)=\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$\begin{align*}P(W=2)&=P(A_w)P(B_w)P(C_r)+P(A_w)P(B_r)P(C_w)+P(A_r)P(B_w)P(C_w)\\\\&=\frac{3}{8}\frac{8}{11}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8}\frac{3}{11}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{8}\frac{8}{11}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{73}{176}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!But why do you switch to getting the red ball from basket A? It might be a little silly, but I am just not sure I understand that part. Mathematically it makes sense to me, but can you explain a little more theoretically? Basically, how do you know which balls come from which basket for P(W=2)?

Comment: It is not silly. For W=2 we have to consider all cases (there are 3 possible). Pay attention that this is $P(W=2)$ not $P(W=2|A_w)$ so for this probability we need also to consider the case that A is red

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C$ be the event of selecting a white marble from the relevant container.

$$\mathsf P(A) = 3/8, \mathsf P(B) = 8/11, \mathsf P(C) = 1/2$$

We want:  $$\require{cancel} \begin{align}
\mathsf P(A\mid ABC^c\cup AB^cC\cup A^cBC)
 & = \frac{\mathsf P(ABC^c\cup AB^cC)}{\mathsf P(ABC^c\cup AB^cC\cup A^cBC)}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{\mathsf P(A)\Big(\mathsf P(B)\mathsf P(C^c)+\mathsf P(B^c)\mathsf P(C)\Big)}{\mathsf P(A)\Big(\mathsf P(B)\mathsf P(C^c)+\mathsf P(B^c)\mathsf P(C)\Big)+\mathsf P(A^c)\mathsf P(B)\mathsf P(C)}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{\frac 3 8\big(\frac 8 {11}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{11}\frac 1 2\big)}{\frac 3 8\big(\frac 8 {11}\frac 12+\frac 3 {11}\frac 1 2\big)+ \frac 5 8\frac 8 {11}\frac 1 2}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{33\cancel{/176}}{73\cancel{/176}}
\end{align}$$